# How to get user names of all groups using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to read all member names of all groups using Graph API

**My Method**

```
var unternehmen = await graphManager
    .Client
    .Groups
    .Request()
    .Expand("members")
    .GetAsync();

foreach (var gruppe in unternehmen)
{
    Debug.Log("  " + gruppe.Id + " " + gruppe.DisplayName);

    foreach (var member in gruppe.Members)
    {
         Debug.Log(member.Id);
    }         
}
```

**Response**

> Only Member ID's and all Group Names

What I need is **all** names of **all** groups. How can I get those?

Comment: Which api did you use?

Comment: @Tiny-wa https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0

Comment: Via 'graph/microsoft.com/v1.0' can only get response like '{"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata","value":[{"name": "invitations","kind": "EntitySet","url": "invitations"}]}', more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to caste the members to **Microsoft.Graph.User** first because not all members are users.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/microsoft.graph.user
```

C# code:

```
var groups = await graphClient.Groups
    .Request()
    .Expand("members")
    .GetAsync();

foreach (var gruppe in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{gruppe.Id}, {gruppe.DisplayName}");

    // another method to get members
    // var members = await graphClient.Groups[gruppe.Id].Members.Request().GetAsync();
    
    var members = gruppe.Members;
    var userMembers = members.Where(m => m.ODataType == "#microsoft.graph.user").Cast<User>();
    foreach (User user in userMembers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{user.Id}, {user.DisplayName}");
    }

}
```